# Buscador por filtros en laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estoy haciendo una búsqueda avanzada. 
Básicamente, lo que tengo es un botón (Filtro) que abre un modal con un form (método = GET) y cuatro entradas (name, code, start_date, end_date).

Lo que tengo que hacer es que, por ejemplo, si solo filtro para el campo de nombre, la URL es http://xxxxxxx.dev/events?name=xxx (mostrando un span con el filtro, en esta caso mostrar el filtro name). Si filtra por el nombre y el campo de código, la URL es http://xxxxxxx.dev/events?name=xxxxx&code=xxxx (en este caso mostrar el filtro name y code)

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que usar [local scope](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#query-scopes)

Por ejemplo:

(model)

```
 public function scopePopular($query)
    {
        return $query->where('votes', '>', 100);
    }
```

(controller)

```
$eventos = Events::popular()->get();
```

Comment: Sisi, el buscador funciona perfecto! El problema es que cuando mando el formulario solo con el campo name la url es http://xxxxxxx.dev/events?name=xxxxx&code=&start_date=&end_date= y lo que estoy buscando es hacer que esta sea http://xxxxxxx.dev/events?name=xxxxx, me comprendes?

Comment: No mucho la verdad, pero mándalo todo siempre aunque ande vació y en el controlador compruebas que llegue con `$request->has('atributo')` y/o `empty()`.